# Adding a css classname to fullcalendar event to fill entire day with event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add a classname 'fc-event-height-override' to my event so that a single event fills the entire day box.

```
{
       title: 'Sales Meeting',
       start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
       end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
       allDay: false,
       className: 'fc-event-height-overirde'
}
```

I can get the box to fill mostly but the top part is still visible. I have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/437/) here that shows the day area isn't being completely filled with the event.

Here is some code for the calendar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      var nextEventLeft = element.offset().left + element.width() + 5;
      element.parent().children().eq(element.index() + 1).css('left', nextEventLeft);
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    year: y,
    month: m,
    date: d,

    slotMinutes: 15,
    editable: true,

    events: [{
      title: 'Sales Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
      allDay: false,
      className: 'fc-event-height-overirde'
    }]

  });

  console.log($('#calendar').html());

});
```

```css
.fc-event-height-overirde {
  height: 100px !important;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div style="border:solid 1px red;">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```